# D3 line chart shows Y value change earlier than corresponding X Value (Date)

Tags: d3.js

Please see my stackblitz to see the issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-playground-d3-p15rtc?file=step-chart.ts,package.json,index.html,data-ts.ts,domain.ts

I was expecting the value of 70 should come after the 21st of April, but they drew it on the 20th of April itself.

[image]

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your using [`d3.curveStep`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v3.2.0/README.md#curveStep) - it draws the steps using
the data as *midpoints* which alters your chart completely - a vertical line is drawn at half-way between x axis times.

One solution is to use `d3.curveStepAfter`, but that doesn't work with your grouping of points in a pair, since this way you loose one point. This is [a fork of your codepan](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-playground-d3-zwa7qm?file=step-chart.ts) that implements this solution, - it's a quick and dirty solution that keeps the second value `endDate` to satisfy type restrictions, but doesn't use it.

I slightly changed the data to better see how things look, and make the y axis to start from zero.

There are, of course, several other solutions possible, for instance keeping the step pairing and treating the last point specially (adding its `endDate` to the line), or using [`d3.curveLinear`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v3.2.0/README.md#curveLinear), or even saving the
`d3.curveStep` method by duplicating the points (adding both
the `startDate` and `endDate` to the line).